# serialized string contains a reference to a class that cannot be instantiated

Tags: php, serialization

"if the serialized string contains a reference to a class that cannot be instantiated (e.g. being abstract) PHP will immediately die with a fatal error. If the unserialize() statement is preceded with a '@' to avoid cluttering the logs with warns or notices there will be absolutely no clue as to why the script stopped working. Cost me a couple of hours..."

I found this on php manual and try to test this but it doesn't throw fatal error if somebody could give example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

```
abstract class Foo {}
unserialize('O:3:"Foo":0:{}');
```

[gives](https://3v4l.org/A4TCW):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Foo in /in/A4TCW:4 Stack trace:
#0 /in/A4TCW(4): unserialize('O:3:"Foo":0:{}')
#1 {main}   thrown in /in/A4TCW on line 4
```

It doesn't matter whether it's just the root object or a property thereof:

```
abstract class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
unserialize('O:3:"Bar":1:{s:1:"a";O:3:"Foo":0:{}}');
```

you [get the same result](https://3v4l.org/ZkdMk):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Foo in /in/ZkdMk:5
Stack trace:
#0 /in/ZkdMk(5): unserialize('O:3:"Bar":1:{s:...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/ZkdMk on line 5
```

---

Unserializing something that simply extends an abstract class is not a problem, and is not what your quote is suggesting.

```
abstract class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
unserialize('O:3:"Bar":0:{}');
```

[works fine](https://3v4l.org/gjDra).

Comment: You're directly unserializing abstract class i am looking for an example where we unserialize child which has a reference to abstract class or in other words extending abstract class.